# Hangfire retry pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, hangfire

It is possible to retry task till condition is not completed ? e.g.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user = new User();
        var jobs = new Jobs();

        Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => jobs.SendNotification(user));
    }
}


public class Jobs
{
    Rules rules = new Rules();

    public void SendNotification(User user)
    {
        if (rules.Rule1() && rules.Rule2())
        {
            // send notification
            return;
        }

        // somehow retry the execution of this method (throw exception does not seem right)
    }
}

public class Rules
{
    public bool Rule1() { return true; }

    public bool Rule2() { return true; }
}

public class User { }
```

I know that it is possible to retry execution of method by throwing exception but that does not seem right, since I know that recovering from exception is rather costly, and it will mark job as failed in hangfire admin interface which is not true.

I could write retry pattern myself, but I like the way hangfire is saving all the information related to background job processing to the persistent storage (SQL in my case), no data is kept in a process’ memory. So I assume it can recover the queue from storage even after server was shut down and continue processing.

Note: i would like to use hangfire because we already using it for the jobs but if it is not suitable I have free hand. Could you recommend some library that can do what I want and you have good experience with it ?

Comment: What are rule1 and rule2? Why would they evaluate differently each time the task runs?

Comment: They can change in time. I found out this hard to achieve so i choosed different approach. Closing the question.

Comment: @ĽubošČurgó you could have your method reschedule itself at a later time (eg 15 minutes) if the conditions are not met.